# MySQL - Unable to create and ENUM column

Tags: mysql, enums

On MySQL 5.1.73 I've created a table with an Enum column as following:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS rollover_profile 
(
    rollover_profile_id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    max_period INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    percentage INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    logical_delete_yn ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    published_yn ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
);
```

but when I inspect the table `logical_delete_yn` and `published_yn` are defined as `ENUM('','')`

I tried on another MySQL server (ver 5.0.77) and there seems to be fine.

Is it some MySQL option wrong?

Comment: Are there version differences between the two servers?  Are there settings differences between the two servers?

Comment: The problem happens on 5.1.73. I'm not sure how (where) to check the settings

Comment: what is your database default charset?

Comment: Side note: Why not just use `BIT` columns instead of a yes/no `ENUM`?

Comment: with which tool u inspected table? can u make a screenshot?

Comment: Toad for MySQL. I also get _java.sql.SQLException: Column 'logical_delete_yn' has duplicated value ''_ in ENUM when trying to update the table.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff please don't open that door :) I didn't design the database and cannot make changes. We are migrating an existing one to a new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the charset on the new server had been changed to UCS2. Changing it to UTF8 solved the issue.

The weird thing is that changing the query to

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS rollover_profile 
(
    rollover_profile_id BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    max_period INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    percentage INT(10) NOT NULL, 
    type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    description VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
    logical_delete_yn ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
    published_yn ENUM('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
);
```

or to anything where the two ENUMs don't have the same values works fine on UCS2.